# Angular Reactive Form _updateTreeValidity

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to loop over a form array in a fromgroup that I have as below

```
public publisherForm = new FormGroup({
        books: new FormArray([])
    });


public get books(): FormArray{
    return this.publisherForm.controls.coverages as FormArray
}

<ng-container formArrayName="books" *ngFor="let book of books.value; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                <book [bookFormGroup]="book"></book>
            </ng-container>
```

In the book component I have a getter like this:

```
public get bookGroup(): FormGroup {
        return this.bookFormGroup as FormGroup
    }
```

In my book component it is super simple like below:

```
 <form [formGroup]="bookGroup">
</form>
```

Now when I load these pages I am I get an error that I have not been able to solve or find much about online.

**TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function**

**Error: Cannot find control with name: '0'**

Answer (score 0):

this is heppend because this: `[formGroupName]="i"` which `i` is in the first iteration equal to 0 ... acttualy you don't need it, so you can remove `[formGroupName]="i"` and also this `formArrayName="books"` and leave it like this:

```
`<ng-container *ngFor="let book of books.controls">
            <book [bookFormGroup]="book"></book>
        </ng-container>
```

it will work just fine

Comment: Even after removing both of these I still get the same error for _updateTreeValidity

Comment: the `FormArray` can't stay empty if you menipulate it inside `BookComponent` - you must initialize it with one `FormControl` or `FormGroup`

Comment: Once I get the data from the observable I add form groups into the array.

Comment: I seem to only get this when i do push onto the form array